# StreamHandler logging multiple times in python logging

Tags: python, unit-testing, logging, automation, python-logging

I'm using Python logging along with config file, currently in my config file I've defined 3 loggers namely root, FileLogger and ConsoleLogger. The config file is as given below:

```
[loggers]
keys=root,fileLogger, consoleLogger

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler, fileHandler_DEBUG, fileHandler_INFO,
        fileHandler_WARNING, fileHandler_ERROR, fileHandler_CRITICAL,
        consoleHandler_DEBUG, consoleHandler_INFO, consoleHandler_WARNING,
        consoleHandler_ERROR, consoleHandler_CRITICAL

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler

[logger_fileLogger]
level=DEBUG
handlers=fileHandler_DEBUG, fileHandler_INFO, fileHandler_WARNING, fileHandler_ERROR, fileHandler_CRITICAL
qualname=FileLogger
propagate=0

[logger_consoleLogger]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler_DEBUG, consoleHandler_INFO, consoleHandler_WARNING, consoleHandler_ERROR, consoleHandler_CRITICAL
qualName=ConsoleLogger
propagate=0

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)


#All filehandlers are given below

[handler_fileHandler_DEBUG]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=({"./LogFiles/debug.log"})

[handler_fileHandler_INFO]
class=FileHandler
level=INFO
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=({"./LogFiles/info.log"})

[handler_fileHandler_WARNING]
class=FileHandler
level=WARNING
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=({"./LogFiles/warning.log"})

[handler_fileHandler_ERROR]
class=FileHandler
level=ERROR
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=({"./LogFiles/error.log"})

[handler_fileHandler_CRITICAL]
class=FileHandler
level=CRITICAL
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=({"./LogFiles/critical.log"})


#All ConsoleHandlers are given below

[handler_consoleHandler_DEBUG]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_consoleHandler_INFO]
class=StreamHandler
level=INFO
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_consoleHandler_WARNING]
class=StreamHandler
level=WARNING
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_consoleHandler_ERROR]
class=StreamHandler
level=ERROR
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_consoleHandler_CRITICAL]
class=StreamHandler
level=CRITICAL
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
```

Now, For consuming the config file, I've created package and the file in the package is as follows:

```
import logging.config

class PipelineLogger:
    """
    A class to create logger object.

    ----------

    Attributes:
        name : str
            name of the logger
        loggerFileObj : Child logger object
                        logger which deals with file logging
        loggerFileObj : Child logger object
                    logger which deals with console logging
    Methods:
        debug(str, str) -> boolean

        info(str, str) -> boolean

        warn(str, str) -> boolean

        error(str, str) -> boolean

        critical(str, str) -> boolean

    Methods
    -------
    """
    def __init__(self, name):
        logging.config.fileConfig('./config/loggerConfig.conf')
        self.loggerFileObj = logging.getLogger('FileLogger')
        self.loggerConsoleObj = logging.getLogger('ConsoleLogger')
        self.name = name

    def debug(self, msg, caller_function):
        '''
        This function will call the logger's debug method

        :param msg: Any message that needs to be displayed/showed to developer
        :param caller_function: Line number in which we're calling the debug method
        :return: True - for successful execution, False - if we encountered an error
        '''

        try:
            self.loggerConsoleObj.debug(caller_function + ' :  ' + msg)
            self.loggerFileObj.debug(caller_function + ' :  ' + msg)
            return True
        except Exception:
            return False


    def info(self, msg, caller_function):
        """
        This function will call the logger's info method

        :param msg: Any message that needs to be displayed/showed to developer
        :param caller_function: Line number in which we're calling the debug method
        :return: True - for successful execution, False - if we encountered an error
        """
        try:
            self.loggerConsoleObj.info(caller_function + ' : Console  ' + msg)
            self.loggerFileObj.info(caller_function + ' : File ' + msg)
            return True
        except Exception:
            return False

    def warn(self, msg, caller_function):
        """
        This function will call the logger's warning method

        :param msg: Any message that needs to be displayed/showed to developer
        :param caller_function: Line number in which we're calling the debug method
        :return: True - for successful execution, False - if we encountered an error
        """
        try:
            self.loggerConsoleObj.warning(caller_function + ' : Console  ' + msg)
            self.loggerFileObj.warning(caller_function + ' : File ' + msg)
        except Exception:
            return False

    def error(self, msg, caller_function):
        """
        This function will call the logger's error method

        :param msg: Any message that needs to be displayed/showed to developer
        :param caller_function: Line number in which we're calling the debug method
        :return: True - for successful execution, False - if we encountered an error
        """
        try:
            self.loggerFileObj.error(caller_function + ' : File  ' + msg)
            self.loggerConsoleObj.error(caller_function + ' : Console  ' + msg)
            return True
        except Exception:
            return False

    def critical(self, msg, caller_function):
        """
        This function will call the logger's critical method

        :param msg: Any message that needs to be displayed/showed to developer
        :param caller_function: Line number in which we're calling the debug method
        :return: True - for successful execution, False - if we encountered an error
        """
        try:
            self.loggerConsoleObj.critical(caller_function + ' : Console  ' + msg)
            self.loggerFileObj.critical(caller_function + ' : File ' + msg)
            return True
        except Exception:
            return False
```

And finally the consumer of the logger object or which tests the logger code is as below:

```
from py_lib import pipeline_logger
from py_lib.pipeline_logger import pipeline_logger_module

myCustomLogger = pipeline_logger_module.PipelineLogger('yash')

print(myCustomLogger.name)

myCustomLogger.debug("First Test debug msg", "test_pipeline_runner.py line 8")
myCustomLogger.info("First Test info msg", "test_pipeline_runner.py line 9")
myCustomLogger.warn("First Test warn msg", "test_pipeline_runner.py line 10")
myCustomLogger.error("First Test error msg", "test_pipeline_runner.py line 11")
myCustomLogger.critical("First Test critical msg", "test_pipeline_runner.py line 12")
```

Now the problem is that the fileLogger works as expected and there is no multiple entries of log in log files. BUT in console logging the info log is printed twice, the warn log thrice and so on, at last the critical log is printed 5 times in console!

Answer (score 0):

There might be a bit of misunderstanding of how handlers work. When you create a handler like this:

```ini
[handler_consoleHandler_INFO]
class=StreamHandler
level=INFO
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)
```

it will log everything above and equal to the `INFO` level. It means that every `myCustomLogger.info`, `myCustomLogger.warning`, `myCustomLogger.error` and `myCustomLogger.critical` will log through the `handler_consoleHandler_INFO`.

In your case,

| handler | level | levels that will be logged through the handler |
| --- | --- | --- |
| handler_consoleHandler_DEBUG | DEBUG | DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR, CRITICAL |
| handler_consoleHandler_INFO | INFO | INFO, WARNING, ERROR, CRITICAL |
| handler_consoleHandler_WARNING | WARNING | WARNING, ERROR, CRITICAL |
| handler_consoleHandler_ERROR | ERROR | ERROR, CRITICAL |
| handler_consoleHandler_CRITICAL | CRITICAL | CRITICAL |

So, as you can see, a `myCustomLogger.critical("message")` will be processed and logged through the 5 different handlers, giving you the 5 duplicate logs that you saw.

To fix this, the solution is simple. You don't need that many different console handlers. Since all your console handlers are given the same arguments (except the `level`), you can do with just one (`consoleHandler`):

```ini
[loggers]
keys=root,fileLogger, consoleLogger

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler, fileHandler_DEBUG, fileHandler_INFO, fileHandler_WARNING, fileHandler_ERROR, fileHandler_CRITICAL

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler

[logger_fileLogger]
level=DEBUG
handlers=fileHandler_DEBUG, fileHandler_INFO, fileHandler_WARNING, fileHandler_ERROR, fileHandler_CRITICAL
qualname=FileLogger
propagate=0

[logger_consoleLogger]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler
qualName=ConsoleLogger
propagate=0


#All filehandlers are given below

[handler_fileHandler_DEBUG]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=({"./LogFiles/debug.log"})

[handler_fileHandler_INFO]
class=FileHandler
level=INFO
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=({"./LogFiles/info.log"})

[handler_fileHandler_WARNING]
class=FileHandler
level=WARNING
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=({"./LogFiles/warning.log"})

[handler_fileHandler_ERROR]
class=FileHandler
level=ERROR
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=({"./LogFiles/error.log"})

[handler_fileHandler_CRITICAL]
class=FileHandler
level=CRITICAL
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=({"./LogFiles/critical.log"})


# All ConsoleHandlers are given below

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
```

Then, do:

```py
import logging.config

logging.config.fileConfig("./config/loggerConfig.conf")

consolelogger = logging.getLogger("ConsoleLogger")

consolelogger.error("Error message")
```

and it gives only one line:

```
2023-02-10 11:55:50,287 - ConsoleLogger - ERROR - Error message
```